# Design an algorithm to check if point lies on a Bézier curve

Tags: polynomials, algorithms, bezier-curve

I'm trying to create an algorithm that could tell if a point lies on a Bézier curve (or very close to it) analytically.

I know that I can check if that's the case by solving $t$ for some ${x,y}$:

$x = a_x(1-t)^3 + 3b_xt(1-t)^2 + 3c_xt^2(1-t)+d_xt^3$

$y = a_y(1-t)^3 + 3b_yt(1-t)^2 + 3c_yt^2(1-t)+d_yt^3$

and if it has solutions in range $[0,1]$, then the point belongs to a Bézier.

$a_x, a_y, ... d_x, d_y $ are Bézier's start point, controls points and end point.

I know how to do that on a piece of paper if I substitute $a_x, a_y, ... d_x, d_y $ with some values, but I have no idea how to create an algorithm for doing that with my computer (mainly because I'm not able to combine polynomial terms since they are connected to $a_x, a_y, ... d_x, d_y $). Could someone please point me to a technique that can be used in such cases or to some source code that does what I want to achieve?

Comment: Another possibility is to find the point on the Bézier curve that is closest to the given point.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to eliminate ("Elimination" is an important keyword) variable $t$ in order to turn your parametric representation into a cartesian implicit equation $f(x,y)=0$, because it is easy to test if $f(x,y)=0$ or, more realisticaly, $ -\varepsilon < f(x,y) < + \varepsilon$ for some small $\varepsilon$.

How to do that ? The answer, adapted to computer programs, is : by using **Sylvester's resultant**. I refer you to the recent answer I made [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2537883/transforming-quadratic-parametric-curve-to-implicit-form/2537941#2537941) in a similar case.

In order to simplify a little the computations, let us assume that the initial point ($t=0$) is the origin (it is always possible to do that), expanding  formulas for $x$ and $y$ as polynomials in $t$ :

$$\begin{cases}U_xt^3+V_xt^2+W_xt-x=0\\ U_yt^3+V_yt^2+W_yt-y=0\end{cases}$$

$$\begin{cases}U_x&:=&3b_x-3c_x+d_x\\V_x&:=&3c_x-6b_x\\ W_x&:=& 3b_x\end{cases} \ \ \text{and} \ \ \begin{cases}U_y&:=&3b_y-3c_y+d_y\\V_y&:=&3c_y-6b_y\\ W_y&:=& 3b_y\end{cases}$$

one gets the following $6 \times 6$ "determinantal" expression for $f$:

$$f(x,y)=\left|\begin{array}{rrrrrrrr}
U_x&V_x&W_x&-x&0&0\\
0&U_x&V_x&W_x&-x&0\\
0&0&U_x&V_x&W_x&-x\\
U_y&V_y&W_y&-y&0&0 \\
0&U_y&V_y&W_y&-y&0\\
0&0&U_y&V_y&W_y&-y
\end{array}\right|=0.$$

You can leave it under this form if you use a software like Matlab. But if you have to do the operation $\approx10^9$ times, you need to expand it once for all (using a CAS).

Comment: I have added the explicit formula (in the case where $A$ is considered as the origin).

Comment: We just had an exchange with @CADJunkie who advised to look at the works of Tom Sederberg. He has written a book  (http://tom.cs.byu.edu/~557/text/cagd.pdf) avalable on line where you will find uses of resultants in the Bézier framework.

Comment: Thank you very much! I thought that maybe there exists some efficient algorithm for doing that and I could use it in my application but it seems to me now that I should rather approximate curves with lines. But I'll implement what you described anyway, just to learn something new, so, once again, thank you!

Comment: Thanks for your thanks...

Comment: @JeanMarie Hi, I'm wondering if you might be able to provide a new link to that book you referred to? Seems that the link is dead >.<

Comment: @netigger Indeed... Here's is a link to a rather old publication :[https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Ronald_Goldman2/publication/220066977_Some_applications_of_resultants_to_problems_in_computational_geometry/links/5447cfaf0cf2f14fb812eb47/Some-applications-of-resultants-to-problems-in-computational-geometry.pdf]

Comment: @JeanMarie Hi, I think that there is a small mistake with the "determinantal" matrix.   Shouldn't it always be square? In my limited understanding of a Sylvester matrix, it has to be 6x6, since both polynomials have a degree of 3.

Comment: @andreas Thanks ! A determinant $7 \times 8$ surely doensn't exist ! I am going to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

See my answer to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/527005/find-value-of-t-at-a-point-on-a-cubic-bezier-curve).

Elimination and implicitization are the key ideas, as @Jean Marie points out.

The comments mention [these notes by Tom Sederberg](https://scholarsarchive.byu.edu/facpub/1/). In chapter 17 of those notes, you will find some very simple techniques for "inversion" of polynomial and rational curves, based on the use of resultants.
Specifically, on page 204, you will find a formula for doing "inversion" of a cubic curve written in Bezier form, and there's a nice worked example on page 205. This is exactly what you need.

Sederberg's approach is somewhat simpler than the Sylvester resultant, and it does not require converting the curve into algebraic form. The conversion occasionally causes numerical problems, though it should be OK with cubic curves.

If the given point (call it $\mathbf{P}$) is not exactly on the curve, you can apply the inversion formula, anyway, and it will give you some value of $t$. I'm not 100% sure what point this value of $t$ represents. I don't think it's the point on the curve that's closest to $\mathbf{P}$, but it should be good enough if $\mathbf{P}$ is already very close to the curve.

Comment: You are right in that Bezout's  resultant is more "economical" than Sylvester's resultant.

Comment: The link to the Tom Sederberg notes is dead, but it is archived on the [Wayback Machine](https://web.archive.org/web/20170623015322/http://tom.cs.byu.edu/~557/text/cagd.pdf).

Comment: search for Sederberg BYU CAGD

Comment: A more persistent link is: https://scholarsarchive.byu.edu/facpub/1/

Answer (score 0):

I google similar problem about this and somebody gives a more straight way to check if any point is on the bezier curve.

The background for me is, in my drawing application, I need to use mouse to move a bezier curve, first I need to know if the mouse is over it.

The core logic is divide the bezier curve into smaller pieces, and check the endpoints of them, get the nearest endpoint, then divide its neighbouring pieces to find a nearer endpoint of its sub pieces.

No extra math knowledge required.

The error parameter is relative to the line width of the curve.

```
function checkPointOnCubicBezierCurve(controlPoints, p, startT = 0, endT = 1, error =1) {
  var t = startT;
  var minDistance = Infinity,
  minDistanceT = null;
  var count = 100;
  var step = (endT - startT) / count;
  
  // condition to quit recursion
  var startP = pointOnCubicBezierCurve(controlPoints, startT); // get start point of the slice of curve
  var endP = pointOnCubicBezierCurve(controlPoints, endT); // get end point of the slice of curve
    
  if(distanceBetweenPoints(p1, p2)<=error){
    return false;
  }
  
  for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    var point = pointOnCubicBezierCurve(controlPoints, t);
    var dst = distanceBetweenPoints(point, p);
    if (dst < minDistance) {
      minDistance = dst;
      minDistanceT = t;
    }
    if (dst <= error) {
      return true;
    }
    t += step;
  }
  return checkPointOnCubicBezierCurve(controlPoints, p, minDistanceT - step,minDistanceT + step, error);
}
```